# kibana create index, POST is not working

Tags: kibana

kibana create index is not working.

PUT, GET is working.

POST is not working.

kibana > dev tools > console

```
PUT a_test_index

GET _cat/indices

yellow open data_audit   MnC9Y9yFTJKqLCKGwqq2NQ 5 1 3 0 25.9kb 25.9kb
yellow open .kibana      ZCXbosazThOHyKVOIvlJ4A 1 1 2 0 10.7kb 10.7kb
yellow open a_test_index CdPLIvMaTryyYOmdGBBC6A 5 1 0 0  1.1kb  1.1kb

POST a_test_index/doc/1 { "test1": "test2" }

Nothing happened.
```

browsers developer tools.

f12.

no error.

```
GET a_test_index/_search

{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

kibana > management > index pattern

index pattern: a_test_index

create

Nothing happened. The index was not configured.

browsers developer tools.

f12.

Failed to load resource:

the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

:5601/api/...

Comment: It is resolved by unlocking all indexes.

Comment: how did you unlock all indexes?